# Getting OAuth error type when posting opengraph or wallpost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, client-side

We have a sandbox app for development, but since this morning, our sandbox app are unable to post any wallpost or opengraph to feeds page or timeline. We are getting an error message like this for posting wallpost

```
Object {error: Object}
error: Object
code: 368
message: "Warning: This Message Contains Blocked Content: Some content in this message has been reported as abusive by Facebook users."
type: "OAuthException"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

And we are getting error for posting opengraph

```
"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."
```

The path we use to load the object is eg. `fb-api.ourdomain.com/fbapi/{ourappname}/opengraph/{action_object}/gift_id/{gift_id}`, and we put this domain name to the debugger at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, we got an error message

```
Error Parsing URL:  Error parsing input URL, no data was scraped.
```

but once we changed to `fb-test.ourdomain.com/fbapi/{ourappname}/opengraph/{action_object}/gift_id/{gift_id}`
the debugger can return the object information.

So our question is, are we not allowed to use fb related name as our sub-domain name (but we cannot see that in the platform policy page: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/)? Or our sandbox app and object link got blocked because we created too many testing wallpost?

If it is the later case, why we cannot use the same object URL in other app? It looks like the object URL got blocked.

Thanks!